# Review mac tag and rename to Macintosh

Tags: discussion, tags

As said by Takkat in [his previous question](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7823/what-happened-to-the-tag-mac-address) the [mac](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/mac) tag is prone to be misused to ask about mac addresses so I propose:

1. Review that all the use of [mac](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/mac) are about... Macintosh.
2. Rename the [mac](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/mac) to [macintosh](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/macintosh) as U&L have.

The first is to prevent that when we rename things gets ape. A good way is looking at [mac](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/mac) + [network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/network)-ing and check that firsts.

Then our super mods can rename the whole tag to something that is understandable.

Comment: I think this is a good idea.